# restore replacement iphone 5 from damaged iphone 5

Tags: password, restore

I received a replacement iphone 5 which I'm trying to restore within itunes. I'd like to restore it from my damaged, identical iphone 5; however, I don't remember the password which iTunes requires for further steps. I've tried all my usual passwords and nothing works. I'm running out of tries before it locks me out.

Comment: start at https://iforgot.apple.com If you can't remember your Apple ID & password for the first phone… you'll have little luck with the second

Answer (score 1):

Apple has created help for such situation.

```
If you forgot the Apple ID use the https://iforgot.apple.com/appleid
```

- If you forgot the password or the Apple ID use the
- Answer your security questions

Use these steps if you know the answers to your security questions:

Select “Answer security questions,” then click Next.
Select your birth date, then click Next.
Answer your security questions.
Set a new password and select Reset Password.

```
Manage your Apple ID primary, rescue, alternate, and notification email addresses
```

Add, change, or delete the several types of email addresses you can use with your Apple ID account. Primary email address

```
Every Apple ID account has one primary email address, and that address is your Apple ID. When you create an Apple ID, you enter the primary address to use as your Apple ID.
```

Your primary address is also the contact email address for your account. Check it regularly, because it receives email that you need to manage your account. For example, before you can use a new or changed Apple ID, you need to verify it as directed in a verification email that Apple sends to that address. Didn't receive the email?